# How to know when all controls and templates are loaded (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I am trying to lazy load the Image Source for the Image Control but the problem is that I have to wait for all controls loaded so that I can use VisualTreeHelper to access to the Image control (which inside a datatemplate).

I tried with Loaded event, LayoutUpdated even, ApplyTemplate like in [the manual of msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596558%28vs.95%29) but for all of them, when I tried to get the container for Image Control, it is null

```
    var containerItem = FeedsPanorama.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex);

    var imageControl = VisualElementHelper.FindName<Image>("ImageThumbnail", containerItem);

    new ImageUtility().GetImageAsyn(new Uri(selectedItem.SummaryImageLink, UriKind.Absolute), imageControl);
```

The same code will work when I handle in Selection_Changed event of FeedsPanaroma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to work around so that I don't have to deal with the Loaded Event. I wrote a new ImageConverter so that I can use that tag to replace the Image tag. It works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Loaded event for the page?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work:(. It is called before all controls are loaded

Comment: Interesting, and the Loaded event for the control in question too?

Comment: yes, and the Loaded event for the control in question as well. if you read the manual link I post: "The timing of the Loaded event in Silverlight differs from the timing of the FrameworkElement.Loaded event in WPF. Specifically, the WPF Loaded event occurs after the template is applied. In Silverlight, the Loaded event is not guaranteed to occur after the template is applied. "